# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qmake, qt-quick

I get the above titled error when running qmake with a cloned github project. Following is the project file.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-01-18T22:28:41
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets webkitwidgets sql gui-private xml 


TARGET = zeal
target.path = /usr/bin
INSTALLS = target
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    zeallistmodel.cpp \
    zealsearchmodel.cpp \
    zealdocsetsregistry.cpp \
    zealsearchresult.cpp \
    zealnativeeventfilter.cpp \
    lineedit.cpp \
    zealsearchitemdelegate.cpp \
    zealsearchitemstyle.cpp \
    zealsettingsdialog.cpp \
    zealnetworkaccessmanager.cpp \
    zealsearchquery.cpp \
    progressitemdelegate.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    zeallistmodel.h \
    zealsearchmodel.h \
    zealdocsetsregistry.h \
    zealsearchresult.h \
    zealnativeeventfilter.h \
    lineedit.h \
    zealsearchitemdelegate.h \
    zealsearchitemstyle.h \
    zealsettingsdialog.h \
    xcb_keysym.h \
    zealnetworkaccessmanager.h \
    zealsearchquery.h \
    progressitemdelegate.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    zealsettingsdialog.ui


QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

macx:DEFINES += OSX
macx:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc+
macx:CONFIG += c++11

win32:DEFINES += WIN32 QUAZIP_BUILD
DEFINES += ZEAL_VERSION=\\\"20140110\\\"
LIBS += -lz

unix:!macx: LIBS += -lxcb -lxcb-keysyms
unix:!macx: SOURCES += xcb_keysym.cpp
unix:!macx: DEFINES += LINUX

icons.path=/usr/share/pixmaps/zeal
icons.files=icons/*
desktop.path=/usr/share/applications
desktop.files=zeal.desktop
unix:INSTALLS += icons desktop

include (widgets/widgets.pri)
include (quazip/quazip.pri)
```

Comment: It seems that this file doesn't mention Quick module. Maybe .pre files are doing that? (See last two lines). What Qt version do you use?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to build with Qt4? This project requires Qt5.

Comment: What project is that? I can only find the file in https://github.com/jkozera/zeal/ which is offline. But the .pro file looks like a Qt Widgets application and not a Qt Quick application.

Comment: yeah the giithub page doesn't sem to work now.but it worked fine two days ago.

Comment: Okay, it's up again. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Run `qmake --version` to check the Qt version you are using. You need Qt 5.0 or higher.

You might want to double check the error message and maybe close other open projects, because zeal is not a QtQuick application. It has no single occurrence of the string "quick" in the whole code (try `git grep -i "quick"`) and no single QML file (try `find . -name "*.qml"`). Thus it is unlikely to throw the given error.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on lubuntu and Qt 5.2.1 (few more modules were unknown).
I removed Qt configuration files from .config folder in my home dir.

```
rm -r ~.config/QtProject
rm ~.config/QtProject.conf
```

Reconfigure project again and all works as expected

Comment: please add how to reconfigure project again!